# UICollectionViewCells in second column are not responding

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

In my application, I have used `UICollectionView`:

[image]

Inside the collection view cell, I have a view button.

If we click on that button, another view will be opened displaying the details of the graph and an enlarged image.

The problem is that if I click on the view button in the cells present of left column i.e. first column everything is working properly, but if I click on the view button in the right side column or 2nd column cells, the detail view does not appear and they become unresponsive.

I do not understand the problem. It is working well for left side cells, then why is it not working for right side cells?

Comment: Please set the background color of button & re-upload the image, so that you & we identify the frame of button.

Comment: post your code in pastebin.com because it seems fine.

Comment: the cells in the second column are not responding , for example if i give only 2 cells, then 1st cell is responding and the second cell is not responding

Comment: Please Paste your whole code some where so that we can find your mistake.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/8MwHstAG

Comment: i have pasted the code for creating the collection view cell there..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your view dimensions and make sure that collection view is not overlapped with other views, it seem that it is not recognisisng the ui gestures at those points..

Answer (score 1):

I got the problem, the problem is i am adding the collection view to a subview named display view and then adding to the parent view, but the main screen frame width is less than the collectionview so the uievents are not recognised at that column part, so i have deleted that display view and added the collection view directly to the parent view and now it is working..